# how to put <section> inline and center

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put boxes in center and to keep them inline.

Here is what I tried:

HTML:

```
<center>
  <section class="box">BOX 1</section>
  <section class="box">BOX 2</section>
</center>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<center>` tag [is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center). Don't use it.

One approach to center the `section` element(s) would be to set their `display` to `inline-block`, remove `float: left`, and then add `text-align: center` to the parent container element. In doing so, the children elements are centered because they are inline-level and they respect the parent element's `text-align` property.

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #0f0;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="box">BOX 1</section>
  <section class="box">BOX 2</section>
</div>
```

Alternatively, using [flexboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes), you could set the parent container element's [`display` to `flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes), and then add [`justify-content: center`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) in order to horizontally center the children flexbox items.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.box {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #0f0;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="box">BOX 1</section>
  <section class="box">BOX 2</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Mine's almost same as yours, so I voted yours up and deleted mine. `:)`

Comment: Im trying to do this all day :D